# How make a dynamic value in MeteorJS

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I need to set a variable or array in meteor JS which whenever changes. Wherever it is used on the page changes.

So far I have tried to set values in session.

```
let in  = Session.get("in");
```

and this in HTML. The following works fine. This changes whenever it detects a change in array

```
   {{#each in}}
        <span class="selectable-tags"> {{this}} </span>
     {{/each}}
```

But whenever I try to add these tags to other div using following. Then the ones added to other div does not change.

```
 "click .selectable-tags"(e, t) {
  // sets the tags inside the Method  box on click 
    var el = e.target.cloneNode(true);
        el.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
        document.querySelector('[contenteditable]').appendChild(el); },
```

using meteor with blaze UI. This can be used as reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693521/using-meteor-js-to-change-the-text-dynamically)

Edit: Session.get or set is given for reference . This was to tell that these values are changing as they on any event triggered wherever set.

Comment: Where exactly did you place this `let in  = Session.get("in");`?

Comment: Please check the edit @Styx

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Actually, I wanted to see your template name, so I would give you an answer that you could just copy/paste and it would work without any changes.

Comment: You're looking for way to make this varaible to be updated every time you're changing something on html page? It won't work automatically, you should update reactive variable yourself.

Comment: Have a look at this for entire code https://jsfiddle.net/7chuq9r8/ @Styx

Comment: Yes You could see the link to the related question It describes my entire problem @Styx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152012/discussion-between-ser-cha-and-styx).

Comment: @Styx Here the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713336/how-to-click-to-add-dynamic-span-to-div-content-in-meteor-js

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a helper that returns the session variable and show the helper in your html code :

```
 Template.yourtemplate.helpers({
   inHelper: ()=> {
     return Session.get('in');
   }    
 )}
```

And in html :

```
<div>{{inHelper}}</div>
```

Every modification on `in` by `Session.set('in', newValue)` will change your HTML.

Comment: Have a look this is to achieve: https://ibb.co/ifYosF 
When I change the Ingredients1 which initially was "sssss" but I changed it to "sssssaaaa". This change was reflected on the tag selection list below the metod box but not in the method div.
When you click on the tag these are added to method box

Comment: I have to add this <div>{{inHelper}}</div> dynamically when the tag is clicked. Then this is inserted into the text box which changes when the in array changes

Comment: Here the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713336/how-to-click-to-add-dynamic-span-to-div-content-in-meteor-js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734028/how-to-create-dynamic-content-in-meteor